# Error: "The operation was rejected by your operating system" when trying to create new angular project using windows powershell

Tags: node.js, angular, powershell

I keep getting the same error message when trying to create a new angular project.
I tried to create a new angular project using Windows Powershell with the following commands:

ng new hello-world

-> Would you like to add angular routing? - Yes

-> Stylesheet format? - CSS

I obtained the error message below. I already tried to reinstall angular cli and I'm running Powershell using Administrator.

*Installed versions:*

Angular CLI: 8.0.6

Node: 10.16.0

OS: win32 x64

**Error message:**

```
npm WARN tarball data for tslint@~5.15.0 (sha512-6bIEujKR21/3nyeoX2uBnE8s+tMXCQXhqMmaIPJpHmXJoBJPTLcI7/VHRtUwMhnLVdwLqqY3zmd8Dxqa5CVdJA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for jasmine-spec-reporter@~4.2.1 (sha512-FZBoZu7VE5nR7Nilzy+Np8KuVIOxF4oXDPDknehCYBDE080EnlPu0afdZNmpGDBRCUBv3mj5qgqCRmk6W/K8vg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for acorn@^6.0.5 (sha512-jPTiwtOxaHNaAPg/dmrJ/beuzLRnXtB0kQPQ8JpotKJgTB6rX6c8mlf315941pyjBSaPg8NHXS9fhP4u17DpGA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/language-service@~8.0.3 (sha512-04XojOo9FJgEQE/rZafnaJQxPEU+//TSzTgpGoIVzCSMx+joCY/ZSSwJZPWxiHlOE57W/zX02ZY+TwcM81oTdw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\konta\Desktop\Programming_files\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\.staging\@angular\platform-browser-447d0944\esm2015\animations\src\animation_builder.js'
npm ERR! path C:\Users\konta\Desktop\Programming_files\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\.staging\jasmine-spec-reporter-cbb15ffc\screenshot.gif
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\konta\Desktop\Programming_files\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\.staging\jasmine-spec-reporter-cbb15ffc\screenshot.gif'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\konta\Desktop\Programming_files\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\.staging\jasmine-spec-reporter-cbb15ffc\screenshot.gif']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\konta\Desktop\Programming_files\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\.staging\jasmine-spec-reporter-cbb15ffc\screenshot.gif'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'C:\\Users\\konta\\Desktop\\Programming_files\\Angular\\hello-world\\node_modules\\.staging\\jasmine-spec-reporter-cbb15ffc\\screenshot.gif' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\konta\\Desktop\\Programming_files\\Angular\\hello-world\\node_modules\\.staging\\jasmine-spec-reporter-cbb15ffc\\screenshot.gif\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\\Users\\konta\\Desktop\\Programming_files\\Angular\\hello-world\\node_modules\\.staging\\jasmine-spec-reporter-cbb15ffc\\screenshot.gif',
npm ERR!   parent: 'hello-world' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\konta\Desktop\Programming_files\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\.staging\@angular\router-8388bfd5\esm2015\src\directives'
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@3.4.4 (sha512-xt5RsIRCEaf6+j9AyOBgvVuAec0i92rgCaS3S+UVf5Z/vF2Hvtsw08wtUTJqp4djwznoAgjSxeCcU4r+CcDBJA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\konta\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-01T01_21_13_653Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the problem: My antivirus was somehow blocking the files without me knowing. It worked once I paused my antivirus during the installation.

Comment: This was my issue too with MalwareBytes

Comment: This can happen with factory configuration in Windows 10 - I had the problem with Windows Defender - see also Qadir Hussain's answer.

Comment: It was MalwareBytes for me too

Answer (score 24):

In windows10 I disabled the windows defender / windows security ==> realtime protection and try again npm install command and it worked

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

NOTE : Turn on the real time protection again after installation complete.

Comment: The issue with this is now you PC or laptop is not protected... There's an option in Windows Security that allows you to exclude files.

Comment: As an absolute newbie to Node, this is horrible. Why would a software as mature as nodejs would need to turn off the virus protection. This is wrong on many level.

Answer (score 16):

Restarting the machine worked for me.

Comment: yup just need restarting the laptop and done..thanks

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem on MAC. I just added 'sudo' before the command and it worked.

```
sudo npm install -g parcel-bundler
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried opening CMD with **Run as Admisnistrator** then run ***npm i*** and it worked for me

Comment: If you are running this command through a terminal in an IDE (eg: Webstorm etc.) you can run the IDE as administrator as well. Then the IDE terminals also get administrator privileges

Answer (score 5):

I'd just like to add a small little answer based on Qadir Hussain's answer.

If you disable "Realtime Protection" in Windows Security, you're going to leave your laptop or PC vulnerable to any viruses that may infect it when "Realtime Protection" is off. This may seem a bit impossible if you're only installing an NPM package, but some apps may have a hidden background process waiting for "Realtime Protection" to be disabled, and when it is, it could inject a virus.

That been said, there's still an option.

1. *First things first, open Windows Security by typing "Windows Security" in the Start Menu and tap "Open".*

[image: Type "Windows Security in the Start Menu and tap "Open".]

2. *After that, go to "Virus & Threat Protection".*

[image: Go to "Virus & Threat Protection".]

3. *Next, scroll down until you find "Manage Settings" under "Virus & Threat Protection Settings".*

[image: Scroll down until you find "Manage Settings" under "Virus & Threat Protection Settings".]

4. *Then, scroll down until you see "Exclusions". Under "Exclusions" there's a link that says "Add or remove exclusions".*

[image: Scroll down until you see the link that says "Add or remove exclusions".]

5. *Once that's done, tap the button that says "Add an exclusion". Then tap "Folder" on the drop-down menu.*

[image: Tap the button that say "Add an exclusion". Then tap "Folder" on the drop-down menu.]

6. *Choose the `node_modules` directory that is giving issues.*
7. *Last but not least, Allow administrative permissions.*
8. *Finally, exit Windows Security.*

I wouldn't recommend excluding your entire Projects folder, as that will disable all scans for the directory.

> Small disclaimer here, I'm only making this answer as a means of helping others without disabling "Realtime Protection". While I'm not encouraging this, this might help fix a common problem.

*Have a good day. :)*

Answer (score 2):

For me, there are several possibilities:

1. Intercepted by anti-virus software, resulting in inoperability.
2. It is locked by IDE, resulting in inoperable.
3. The task is locked by npm running, resulting in inoperable.

Comment: Closing Visual Studio fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

To me, using Windows 10 the only thing that solved this problem was: *exclude the node_modules folder*, open Visual Studio Code in *Admin mode* in the project folder, and execute the following command:

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was with npm version I was using. I changed to a npm version which did not have the bug by using the below command:

```
npm install --global npm@8.3.1
```

I found this solution in a github issue:

[Link to github issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/411)

Hope it helps you like it did me!

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling the `npm start` process and closing the terminal window (I use Hyper Terminal) worked for me (using Win 10).

I was then able to uninstall an npm package and install another.

Comment: I had trouble installig npm packages for my React Native project and killing the npm start process worked for me. You have my thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had visual studio code running. I turned it off and boom! worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

was facing this problem and this is how it got solved :
-stoping the execution of the development server for both front-end and backend:[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1. try admin.
2. make sure other processes does not occupying the folder/file

with me, it was not related to antivirus.
it appears that a process occupied this folder. in my case a node process occupied my node_modules folder.
i found it out by using [process-explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) -  i searched the path end found that a node process using this folder(even though I closed it! very common in windows), so i ended this process and then i did not got this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue What I have done wrong is I had set the `npm registry` to a `local registry`, without knowing that I faced this issue once I reset to  globally using `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above.

Deleting `node_modules` and re-installing did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I tried installing a new npm dependency, jest, with:

```
npm i --save-dev jest
```

I got it working by simply rerunning the command.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was solved, when i turned off my antivirus, and then moved to the location where i have my "node modules" folder and ran the command there.
DONE.

(Run powershell as admin)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. If you are on a mac, just add the word 'sudo' before the command..

Comment: Solution already given in at least one of the other answers.