# Unable to start expo cli through npm start

Tags: npm, react-native, npm-install, expo

All was working fine and I was running the expo version 3.11.5, but the log said to update it to 3.11.7. I ran that command but my project stopped working.

I have McAfee Anti-virus and Windows Firewall, Firewall. The firewall and real file time checking has already been stopped and I have added node.exe toonode.exe in the exclusion of Windows Firewall.

1. I have also placed adb.exe file in the exclusion for McAfee and Windows Firewall
2. I have also placed adb.exe file in the exclusion for McAfee and Windows Firewall.
3. I have also tried running the `npm install - g expo` cli command through Windows Power Shell (Administrator)
4. I have also tried running the `npm install -g expo-cli` command through Windows Power Shell (Administrator).

What else can I do?

Log file for complete error:

```
PS C:\Users\MY PC\My_React_Native\fruits-vegetables> npm install --global expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained 
an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained 
npm WARN rollback Rolling back mime@2.4.4 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-pwa-manifest-plugin\node_modules'
npm WARN @expo/image-utils@0.2.12 requires a peer of sharp-cli@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\MY PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\adb.exe'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\MY PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\adb.exe'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\MY PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\adb.exe',
npm ERR!   parent: 'expo-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-24T15_03_46_770Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\MY PC\My_React_Native\fruits-vegetables> npm i -g expo-cli@3.11.7     
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained 
an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained 
an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN rollback Rolling back validator@11.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\xdl\node_modules'
npm WARN @expo/image-utils@0.2.12 requires a peer of sharp-cli@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb
npm ERR! errno -4082
**npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb'**     

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-24T17_42_41_316Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install Expo CLI through NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902934/unable-to-install-expo-cli-through-npm)

Comment: I finally did it !
It was an error for  errno: -4048,
I made a restart for my PC
And cleared the NPM cache
It is working now!
Thanks