# The command create-react-app doesn't run, it creates an error

Tags: reactjs

$ npx create-react-app awesomeApp
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\'
command not found: create-react-app

Comment: Is CRA installed? Installed globally?

Comment: @DrewReese  Global installation of CRA isn't recommended as [using npx will make sure latest version of CRA is used](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start).

Comment: You are getting `EPERM` error. Check [npm - EPERM: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows)

Comment: @AjeetShah Shoot, you're right. It's been a while since I needed to run CRA. My question was based only on `command not found: create-react-app` message.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug within npm if you have your username as "FirstName LastName"

A quick fix for this is -

> If your UserName is - Anand Chavan all you need to use at
>  is ANANDC~1. i.e FirstName+First_Letter_of_your
> LastName+~1 (All in capital)

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\<UserNameWorkAround>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

Example config for - Anand Chavan as username.

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\ANANDC~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as well in Windows. And I solved it as below:

It may be due to your username having space in between your username. If so, kindly try this in your command prompt if you're using Windows:
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global

Thereafter, try again: npx create-react-app awesome

Answer (score 0):

I encountered EPERM errors while trying to clean install create-react-app and running an older version of it.

Excluding the `node_modules` folder from Windows' Virus & Threat Protection ([answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865626/12047713)) and then running my terminal as an administrator fixed it for me.