# how to use brain.js in react js

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, brain.js

I need to know how to use brain.js in react js project made using

```
create-react-app
```

when I try to install it using:

```
npm i brain.js
```

It shows this error:

```
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [                           gl/-/gl-4.9.0.tg
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Swapnil\\online-medical-consultation\\node_modules\\node-abi',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Swapnil\online-me
odules\node-abi\node_modules\.bin'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Swapnil\\online-medical-consultation\\node_modules\\no
n'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.1 found at "C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Loc
39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/node-v14.16.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/node-v14.16.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/win-arm64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 404 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.16.0/win-arm64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-
silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consult
yp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\node-g
js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Swapnil\online
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\node-g
js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\node-g
js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\node-g
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\node-g
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Swapnil\\online-med
odules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-21T10_44_51_288Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation> npm i brain.js
npm ERR! code EPERM                                                            sl-tokenizer rea
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consultation\node_modules\node-abi\node_modules\.
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consulta
i\node_modules\.bin'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Swapnil\online-medical-consul
abi\node_modules\.bin'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Swapnil\\online-medical-consultation\\node_modules\\node-abi\\node
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-21T10_49_59_628Z-debug.log
```

Please tell if u know to fix it...

Comment: Have you read the error message before posting the question? I think you should try what written in error message first and tell us what happened.

Comment: If you still confused, the error tell that you need to install the latest version of visual studio(middle part of error). If you already install and It still error, try to setup properly the path to vs. Also the bottom part said maybe your file opened in another text editor, have you close all the unnecessary text editor? And last part of error said maybe you should run the programs as administrator. Just open your command prompt as administrator then at see what heppened.

Comment: They had the same error as you = > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829352/error-the-operation-was-rejected-by-your-operating-system-when-trying-to-crea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading the latest version

download that one

https://www.npmjs.com/package/brain.js/v/2.0.0-beta.6

reference

https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/issues/752#issuecomment-1076707501

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I faced the same issue
and it's solved with that solution

Comment: I believe you that it helped. What I recommond is to explain why and how it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install MSVC on Windows x64 - https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe
or install g++ and gcc for Linux,  so that your process doesn't hang thus making EPERM.