# I cannot install npm with node, any ideas?

Tags: npm

I have done multiple things to try and get npm install to work.

Currently, I've have changed the file path to the folder which has package.json in it. However, this shows this error message:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.color-support-6lMVV8bL
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.color-support-6lMVV8bL'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.color-support-6lMVV8bL'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\.color-support-6lMVV8bL'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hatfi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-22T22_29_31_807Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to install a package somewhere under `c:\program files`? Please share the exact command you tried to execute and at which location...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "The operation was rejected by your operating system" when trying to create new angular project using windows powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829352/error-the-operation-was-rejected-by-your-operating-system-when-trying-to-crea)